# How can I iterate through only auto filtered rows in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, autofilter

I have very long excel table (400k+ rows) and I need to look up several values in this table. I started out with just a Do Until the first column in the table was blank but this was taking way too long. I then added an AutoFilter step to filter the table down to only matching rows, but I am now struggling to get my code to only loop through the filtered rows. Even though I filtered the table, the code still goes through all 400k+ lines each time.

Here is the code I have currently that isn't working:

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    Dim FilteredRng As Range

    For i = 0 To Components.Count - 1
        Workbooks(Export).Activate
        Sheets("Routings").Select
        MyComp = Components(i)
        
        Range("A2,H106114").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyComp
       
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FilteredRng = Range("A1,H106114").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
' 1b. loop through routes page and find Work Centers

        For j = 2 To FilteredRng.Rows.Count
            If FilteredRng.Cells(j, 1) = MyComp Then
                Call FindGroup(FilteredRng.Cells(j, 4), ImportRow)
            
                Workbooks(Export).Activate
                Sheets("Routings").Select
                        
                End If
        
        Next j
       
0    Next i
```

Comment: `Range("A2,H106114")` did you mean `Range("A2:H106114")` ?  You cannot index into `FilteredRng` using (eg) - `FilteredRng.Cells(j, 1)` that will not work the way you expect, because it's a multi-area (non-contiguous) range.  You need to use a `For Each` after setting `FilteredRng` something like `Set FilteredRng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: The result Range consists of non-contiguous Ranges. Therefore the iteration must be done on the `Range.Areas` object where each `Area` has it's own `Rows` property.

Comment: Use a `For Each` loop as demonstrated in the EDIT of the most upvoted answer in the linked thread.